# python script in QGis - help using gdal.Polygonize

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygonize

I want to create a very simple script in python that polygonizes a raster.
Based on python cookbook + forums search I wrote the following code

```
#import des modules
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

##srcRaster=Raster
##Result=output vector

# 1. Open Raster and get band 1
src_ds = gdal.Open(srcRaster)
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# 2. Create output datasource
Result = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temporary_points", "memory")
Result.startEditing()  
Result.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("ClassNo",     QVariant.String)])
Result.updateFields()
gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, Result, 0, [], callback=None )
```

which ends up with the error "in method 'Polygonize', argument 3 of type 'OGRLayerShadow *".
The truth is, I don't really understand what should be the syntax of gdal_polygonize in a qgis python script (command line can be found here).

Could anybody please help ?

Comment: the third parameter needs to be an instance of the GDAL/OGR vector layer class; you're passing in an instance of the QGIS vector layer class... not the same thing! You might find it easier to call the gdal polygonalize using [processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize', input, field, output)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/polygonize.html)

Comment: oh thanks. processing.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize', input, field, output) did work. No need to take the first band out. no need to create the polygon layer prior to run polygonize either.

Comment: @StevenKay - You should post your comment as an answer :)